# Is the Databricks Dashboards API broken?

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I would like to use the Dashboards API to create dashboard objects, but have noticed that the API does not seem to respect all the attributes in the body of the request. Here is a simple example:

```
import requests

url = f'https://workspace/api/2.0/preview/sql/dashboards'
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer token"}


data = {
  "dashboard_filters_enabled": True,
  "data_source_id": source_id, 
  "name": "dashboard",
}

requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers).json()
```

I get a 200 status code and a response object, but the `dashboard_filters_enabled` is still set to its default value which is `False`:

```
 {'id': '1234',
 'slug': 'dashboard',
 'name': 'dashboard',
 'user_id': 4567,
 'dashboard_filters_enabled': False,
 'widgets': None,
  ...
 }
```

I checked to see if the dashboard object with the name `dashboard` exists and it does, but the only attribute that seems to be changed is the `name` and `data_source_id`, nothing else. I also tried to add a widget, but the `widgets` object is always `None` regardless of the payload in the request.

Does anyone know if this API is working at all? If so, what am I doing wrong? I also found a similar issue [here](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009s7qJhSAI/dashboard-api-create-a-dashboard-object-doesnt-work?_ga=2.218026774.1854352332.1679296151-412865823.1676282547).

Comment: Have the same issue. Unfortunately, Databricks support is non-existent.